# Execution of Static Block in Java

Tags: java, static

I am running following code in Java  :

1) First Code :

```
public class Basic {


    static int a=10;
    static
    {
        a=20;
    }   

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
    System.out.println("Value of Static variable : "+Basic.a);
    }
}
```

Output is : Value of Static variable : 20

2) Second Code :

```
public class Basic {
    static
    {
        a=20;
    }   

    static int a=10;

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
    System.out.println("Value of Static variable : "+Basic.a);
    }
}
```

output is : Value of Static variable : 10

Question :  I am not getting when static block is ran just before main method by JVM , then why I am having different output in 2nd code.
In the first code static block will run just before main method then it will reassign the value of a to 20 , but in the second block of code I am initilization variable 'a' before the block and variable 'a' should have vaule 20 when running the program , but it is having value 10 why ?

Comment: You really have no clue? What is different between the first and the second snippet? What do you conclude?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to understand this is to take that **initialization of static fields and and execution of static initialization blocks are treated the same.** This means that Java will allocate memory for the field (just create the field), then run static initialization in order. If the static initialization block is found before the field, it will be run first, and the value initialization will overwrite it.

The same applies to instance initialization fields and instance fields.

To simplify this, just suppose that Java created a static initialization block for each field initialization, as though your code were written:

```
static int a; static{a = 10;}
static
{
    a=20;
}
```

And this, for the second class:

```
static
{
    a=20;
}   

static int a; static{a = 10;}
```

Then ran static blocks in order.

Comment: If so, then if I move `static int a;` at last the value should be `0` as primitive `int` defaults to value `0` isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

The Java runtime system guarantees that static initialization blocks are called in the order that they appear in the source code. [See related Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html).

For your 2nd code example, here is how the runtime system executes the initializations that follow the declaration. The `a=10` initialization is essentially a static block executed in the order it appears in the source code which is after the `a=20` assignment so value printed is 10 not 20.

```
  public class Basic {
    static int a;

    static
    {
        a = 20;
    }
    static
    {
        a = 10;
    }
```

It is standard good practice to include the declarations first in a class followed by static blocks then constructors and other methods. Intermixing static blocks before the declarations can cause confusion as this example demonstrates.